# Python.h not found when it exists Windows

Tags: c++, netbeans, python-2.7, mingw

I'm simply trying to get this to compile to then continue and do the actual code but whenever I try to compile this it says `fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory` I have tried everything and still. I am using NetBeans and in the "Additional Library Directories" I put `C:/Python27/libs` and in "Include Directories" I put `C:/Python27/include`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Python.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python.h compiler issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125522/python-h-compiler-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python.h itself needs to be in your include path and the library needs to be in your library path.

Comment: Ok so it compiles but how can I access the functions now?