# Can't find Python.h when compiling PyCaffe on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04, pycaffe

I'm trying to install PyCaffe for Python 3.5.3 on AWS EC2 with Ubuntu 14.04 *without* Anaconda, following the [installation instructions](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html#compilation).

I successfully compiled it on the same machine for Python 2.7 but when compiling for version 3.5 I get the following error:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-3-227:~/caffe$ make pycaffe
CXX/LD -o python/caffe/_caffe.so python/caffe/_caffe.cpp
python/caffe/_caffe.cpp:1:52: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>  // NOLINT(build/include_alpha)
```

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349484/compile-opencv-python-h-cant-find-python-h) and performed:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

I found [this](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/4538), so I performed the equivalent command for Python 3.5:

```
for req in $(cat requirements.txt); do sudo pip3.5 install $req; done
```

All installations worked but it didn't fix the problem.

I many other posts on similar problems but not this exact problem (so if you find something please check that it's really the same situation before rushing to say I didn't look well enough).

P.S.

I also saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125522/compiler-cant-find-python-h) but I don't understand which directories to add to the path.

Answer (score 1):

When you do a pip install package,when pip finds new version,it uninstall the current one(dateutil in your case) when the package was installed using certain permission,pip needs the same permission to uninstall/upgrade it.

A quick fix would be to change this

```
`for req in $(cat requirements.txt); do pip3.5 install $req; done` to

for req in $(cat requirements.txt); do sudo pip3.5 install $req; done
```

It seems you dont have permission to access /usr/local/lib/python3.5/ folder as user,the packages that goes in /usr/local are required by the system but only available to you and only you on the system, i assume since only only they are restricted to you and pip want to access assuming that no restriction is there,then it get permission denied ,so you might consider doing

```
for req in $(cat requirements.txt); do  pip3.5 --user yourusername install $req; done
```

the alternative is to remove any restriction to execute and write on that folder 
by doing `chmod -R 777 /usr/local/lib/python3.5/` which is usually not recommended but the problem you need pip to be able to read,write,execute anything in that folder.

Comment: This fixed the permission error I listed above (hence +1), but perhaps you missed the main problem I listed above, which it doesn't fix. Anyway I removed the listed part which is no longer relevant.

Comment: do you have these files enabled in your caffe Makefile.config # Uncomment to use Python 3 (default is Python 2)
# PYTHON_LIBRARIES := boost_python3 python3.5m
# PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/include/python3.5m \
#                 /usr/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/core/include
?

Comment: Yes, I have them, and just now I found that there isn't a `/usr/include/python3.5m' directory at all. There is a '/usr/include/python3.4m' directory, I don't understand why though, cause I installed Python 3.5.3 on the machine.

Comment: do you still have this error ython/caffe/_caffe.cpp:1:52: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory? after installing python-3.5-dev,did you build caffe again?you need to delete build folder and repeat the whole process again..

Comment: Yes, that is the error that I'm having, but I didn't install `python3.5-dev` because it doesn't seem to exist. I'm starting to think that it doesn't exist at all for Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: you might be right....is there any specific reason you could not switch back to 3.4? seems to be available python3.4-dev?

Comment: becareful when you remove 3.5 use sudo apt-get remove python3-dev  ,dont use autoremove

Comment: Caffe makefile includes header files from python 3.5. I'm now trying to go for 3.4 but I'm not sure it's supported.

Comment: Is it makefile itsself or Makefile.config?if its in makefile.config you can change then or use Anaconda to install 3.5